# Hiding symbol (and other weird) fonts from Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, text, font-management

In my Photoshop fonts menu there's a lot of fonts I'll never use, and these get in the way of finding the fonts I do use. Can I hide those never-use fonts from Photoshop? (I'm not sure font management software would work because a lot of these fonts are system fonts and a font manager's solution to my problem is to completely deactivate the font, which would hide that font both from photoshop and the rest of the system, and that would cause problems, I'm sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photoshop loads whatever fonts are active in the system. There's no method within any Adobe application to control the font menus beyond having previews or not.

I believe the only font manager to allow application-specific activation/deactivation is [Suitcase](http://www.extensis.com/suitcase-fusion-4/). I could be incorrect about that. I'm not a Suitcase user for reasons I won't go into.